# Can someone please explain to me what is happening in this web.xml file (security-constraints)

Tags: java, xml, security, web, web.xml

xml file and it contains the following snippet:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>GROUP_SECURE</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>The lot</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/Service1.Service1Soap11Endpoint/</url-pattern>
    .....
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>GROUP-SECURE</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

my understanding is users with the role of GROUP-SECURE can access what is in the web-resource-collection shown above, is this correct or does this work differently from how i understand it?

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP-SECURE` and higer level users will be able to acess to the resources defined in the `<security constraint>` tag. [Look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html#bnccb) for some examples.

Comment: so anyone outside of GROUP-SECURE will not be given access to the specified resources?

Comment: if `GROUP-SECURE` is the top user level yes, but if you have levels in your user hierarchy, users like `SUPER-ADMIN` will be able to see this content also.